# xtemplate - Can I factorise my code?

Tags: latex3, xtemplate

Here's a MWE which is a small example of the use of `xtemplate`. This lines will be used in my first public package I'm working on; in my package, the call of `\UseTemplate` will be done by standard `LaTeX` commands. **My idea is to propose a generic way of producing different types of delimiter construction with a user interface for scaling if the default behaviour is not the good one.**

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xtemplate}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_projetmbc_testing_size_left_tl
\tl_new:N \l_projetmbc_testing_size_right_tl
\tl_new:N \l_projetmbc_testing_arg_tl


\cs_new:Npn \l__projetmbc_create_sizes #1 {
  \str_if_eq:NNTF {#1} {normal}
    {
      \tl_set:Nn
        \l_projetmbc_testing_size_left_tl
        {}
  
      \tl_set:Nn 
        \l_projetmbc_testing_size_right_tl
        {}
    }
    {
      \tl_set:Nn
        \l_projetmbc_testing_size_left_tl  
        {\use:c { #1 l}}
  
      \tl_set:Nn 
        \l_projetmbc_testing_size_right_tl
        {\use:c { #1 r}}
    }
}


\DeclareObjectType
  {_projetmbc_testing_}
  {1}

\DeclareTemplateInterface
  {_projetmbc_testing_}
  {projetmbc_testing}
  {1}
  {
    size : choice { normal, big, Big, bigg, Bigg } 
         = normal,
    arg  : tokenlist
  }

\DeclareTemplateCode
  {_projetmbc_testing_}
  {projetmbc_testing}
  {1}
  {
    size = {
      normal = \l__projetmbc_create_sizes{normal}, 
      big    = \l__projetmbc_create_sizes{big},
      Big    = \l__projetmbc_create_sizes{Big},
      bigg   = \l__projetmbc_create_sizes{bigg}, 
      Bigg   = \l__projetmbc_create_sizes{Bigg}
    },
    arg = \l_projetmbc_testing_arg_tl
  }{
    \AssignTemplateKeys

    $
      \tl_use:N \l_projetmbc_testing_size_left_tl
      (
        \dfrac
          {\tl_use:N \l_projetmbc_testing_arg_tl}
          {\tl_use:N \l_projetmbc_testing_arg_tl}
      \tl_use:N \l_projetmbc_testing_size_right_tl
      )
    $
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\section{Size: normal}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\UseTemplate
  {_projetmbc_testing_}
  {projetmbc_testing}
  {
    arg = UUU
  }
  {}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\section{Size: big}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\UseTemplate
  {_projetmbc_testing_}
  {projetmbc_testing}
  {
    size = big,
    arg  = UUU
  }
  {}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\section{Size: Big}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\UseTemplate
  {_projetmbc_testing_}
  {projetmbc_testing}
  {
    size = Big,
    arg  = UUU
  }
  {}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\section{Size: bigg }

\ExplSyntaxOn

\UseTemplate
  {_projetmbc_testing_}
  {projetmbc_testing}
  {
    size = bigg,
    arg  = UUU
  }
  {}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\section{Size: Bigg}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\UseTemplate
  {_projetmbc_testing_}
  {projetmbc_testing}
  {
    size = Bigg,
    arg  = UUU
  }
  {}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Can I factorise my code a bit more, especially the following lines?

```
\DeclareTemplateCode
  {_projetmbc_testing_}
  {projetmbc_testing}
  {1}
  {
    size = {
      normal = \l__projetmbc_create_sizes{normal}, 
      big    = \l__projetmbc_create_sizes{big},
      Big    = \l__projetmbc_create_sizes{Big},
      bigg   = \l__projetmbc_create_sizes{bigg}, 
      Bigg   = \l__projetmbc_create_sizes{Bigg}
    },
    arg = \l_projetmbc_testing_arg_tl
  }{
    % ...
  }
```

Comment: So, something like `semantex`, but based on `xtemplate`? I was never really able to wrap my head around the concept of `xtemplate` and how it differs from just defining the keys directly using `l3keys`.

Comment: My question is more about coding with `xtemplate`.